# unable to connect python to external sql datatbase

Tags: python, database

I have a python program that works fine with xamp server but when I am trying to access a database on hostinger. but I am getting the following errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 472, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/python_3.4/RPI_CONNECT.py", line 5, in <module>
    class database:
  File "F:/python_3.4/RPI_CONNECT.py", line 13, in database
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='u341930730_m', password='abcd', host='mysql.hostinger.in', database='u341930730_rooms')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 719, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 475, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.hostinger.in:3306' (10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

here is my python program

```
import mysql.connector


class database:
    Rooms = []
    Appliances = []
    Status = []

    column_count = 0
    # create connection to server
    # enter your server details here
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='u341930730_m', password='abcd', host='mysql.hostinger.in', database='u341930730_rooms')


    # create a cursor object
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    # function to get all room names from server
    def get_all_rooms(self):
        # query to get room names
        database.cursor.execute("SELECT roomname FROM NUMBER_OF_ROOMS")

        # store all room names in a list named Rooms defined at begining of class
        for row in database.cursor.fetchall():
            room = row[0]
            self.Rooms.append(room)

    print("All rooms stored in list Rooms")


    # function to get all appliance names from server
    # function requires table name in 'Room' parameter
    # this function should be called after function get_all_rooms
    def get_column_names_of_room(self, Room):
        query = "DESCRIBE " + Room
        database.cursor.execute(query)
        # print all column names
        for row in database.cursor.fetchall():
            self.Appliances.append(row[0])
            #print(row[0])
            database.column_count = database.column_count + 1
        # return column_count
        column_count = database.column_count
        database.column_count = 0
        return column_count


    # function to get status of all appliances from tables in database
    # this function requires table name in 'Room' and column count in 'column_count'
    # this function should be called after get_all_column_names
    def get_status_of_appliances(self, Room, column_count):
        query = "SELECT * FROM " + Room
        database.cursor.execute(query)
        # print all data
        for row in database.cursor.fetchall():
            for i in range(1, column_count):
                self.Status.append(row[i])
                #print(row[i])


    # function to clear lists
    # we need to clear these lists as we are storing this data in dictionary and we don't want duplicate data
    def clear_appliance_and_status_list(self):
        self.Appliances.clear()
        self.Status.clear()

    #function to close connection
    def close_connection(self):
        database.cnx.close()


# _______________________________________________________________________________________________________
# main function body

# create dictionary
workspace = {}

# create a class object
db = database()

db.get_all_rooms()
print(db.Rooms)
for room_name in db.Rooms:
    print(room_name)
    column_count = db.get_column_names_of_room(room_name)
    print(column_count)
    print(db.Appliances)
    db.get_status_of_appliances(room_name, column_count)
    print(db.Status)

    for index in range(0,5):
        app = db.Appliances[index+1]
        status = db.Status[index]
        workspace[app] = status


    db.clear_appliance_and_status_list()
print(workspace)
#close database connection
db.close_connection()
```

please tell me what is wrong and corection if possible.
thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to be a network related thing. Check if the DB is up, your hostname / port and your connectivity.

Comment: Your python script looks fine to me. It's most like a network issue, or your MySQL server is set up to only allow connections from the host it is running on.

Check your MySQL config settings for `bind-address`. If MySQL is bound to IP address `0.0.0.0`, then you will not be able to connect from a different host.

Comment: i also have an android app that fetches the data from the same database it is working fine I have checked the database it is up @DavidSmith

Comment: Are you able to connect to the MySQL server from the machine you're running the python script from using another tool, such as [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) ?

Try to establish whether the issue is the host that you're connecting from, or  the script that you're running.